# Pyspark remove first element of array

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I split a column with multiple underscores but now I am looking to remove the first index from that array... The element at the first index changes names as you go down the rows so can't remove based on any value..

```
Column
abc1_food_1_3
abc2_drink_2_6
abc4_2

split(df.Column, '_').alias('Split_Column')

Split_Column
[abc1, food, 1, 3]
[abc2, drink, 2, 6]
[abc4, 2]
```

now how can I yield:

```
Split_Column
[food, 1, 3]
[drink, 2, 6]
[2]
```

I will be converting the array column back to a string with underscores afterwards.. (concat_ws I believe?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the string before the first underscore, you can do:

```
df.selectExpr('substring_index(Column, "_", -size(split(Column, "_")) + 1)')
```

Example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['abc1_food_1_3'],['abc2_drink_2_6'],['abc4_2']]).toDF('Column')
df
+--------------+
|        Column|
+--------------+
| abc1_food_1_3|
|abc2_drink_2_6|
|        abc4_2|
+--------------+

df = df.selectExpr('substring_index(Column, "_", -size(split(Column, "_"))+1) as trimmed')
df
+---------+
|  trimmed|
+---------+
| food_1_3|
|drink_2_6|
|        2|
+---------+
```

Comment: thank you mck! This solution allows me to split, remove the [0] index, and concat back to a string column all in one step

Answer (score 4):

It seems this might be helpful . --

df=df.withColumn("Split_Column_PROCESSED", F.expr("slice(Split_Column, 2, SIZE(Split_Column))"))

i am adding a snippet using this .

It's performance might be better.

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- COLA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+
|                COLA|
+--------------------+
|        [1, 2, 4, 5]|
|[3, 57, 29, 34, 494]|
+--------------------+


import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df=df.withColumn("FINAL", F.expr("slice(COLA, 2, SIZE(COLA))"))

>>> df=df.withColumn("FINAL", F.expr("slice(COLA, 2, SIZE(COLA))"))
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+-----------------+
|                COLA|            FINAL|
+--------------------+-----------------+
|        [1, 2, 4, 5]|        [2, 4, 5]|
|[3, 57, 29, 34, 494]|[57, 29, 34, 494]|
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course after asking this I found a solution:

`expr("filter(Split_Column, x -> not(x <=> Split_Column[0]))").alias('Split_Column')`

Is there another way this can be done perhaps coupling array_remove and element_at?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below code.

```
expr("filter(Split_Column, (x,i) -> i != 0)").alias("Split_Column") // in this i is index of array.
```